# Accordion Menu not showing on mobile for my website what ever showing on webpage

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

Could you please help out this...

recently I have build Accordion Menu for website on left sidebar

it is showing on computer device but not showing on mobile.

Please review my website (http://www.oraappdata.com/) and let me know what is issue....Thanks in Advance.

Thanks &Regards,
Dayakar k

Comment: Cannot identify by just seeing the output..I Tested in Mobile Its not even rendering in mobile and I am sure its not CSS issue. So you need to check your script how you are rendering it. Second thing width is given in pixels which you can change to percentage to make it responsive.


will be Good if you can post the code to get the solution

Comment: Fix the height of your  `#sidebar-wrapper {  height: 100px;} or some pixel`.its not there